# Book about a young male teen with powers, who I believe is genetically engineered from his father

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m looking for a book whose main character is a boy who has some budding abilities.  I recall him having a younger sister.  I know for a fact that the book was published before 2000, likely in the '80s and up to early '90s, but could go as far back.  It would likely qualify as a young adult novel; light sci-fi / fantasy.

I vaguely recall the following:

- At some point, I believe he has to drink a serum (blue?) which I believe augment his powers.
- There's an evil scientist (a geneticist?) who is his biological father.
- I recall the father genetically modifying his son's embryo.
- I recall there being genetically created lizard like monsters introduced toward the end.

In some ways, the genetically modified premise reminds me of this one from Philip Wylie's *[Gladiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiator_(novel))* (1930), though I don't recall the protagonist's abilities being physically grounded

> The story begins at the turn of the 20th century. Professor Abednego Danner lives in a small, rural Colorado town, and has a somewhat unhappy marriage to a conservative religious woman. Obsessed with unlocking genetic potential, Danner experiments with a tadpole (which breaks through the bowl he's keeping it in), and a pregnant cat, whose kitten displays incredible strength and speed, managing to maul larger animals. Fearing the cat may be uncontrollable, Danner poisons it. When his wife becomes pregnant with their first child, Danner duplicates his experiment on his unknowing wife.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to recall the cover art at all?  Was it a paperback or a hardcover?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Elixir-Gary-Braver-ebook/dp/B004OA64UC has some glancing similarities, but isn't YA.